# Efficient way to do a grouping, then a join to data from a different context/db

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Given the following objects from different databases, what would be the most efficient way of joining them with a LinQ statement and grouping them by QID and then SectionID. Ideally they should of course be in the same DB, but I gotta work with this. Using EF6, so separate context for each db.

Each Question can have many UserAnswer(s)
,there's also a TestResult object in the same DB as UserAnswer, so queries start from its navigation properties.

**UserAnswer**

Line ID [PK]

string Answer

Int QID

Int SectionID

**Question**

int QID [PK]

SectionID [FK]

string QuestionText

Other properties that I wish to project into anonymous type first

Something like the below should work, but was just wondering if there's a more efficient way than performing all the below queries.

```
   var ColOfQDataForQ = Test.TestSections.SelectMany(x => x.TestQuestions.Select(q => new {q.QID, q.SID, AllMustBeCorrect = q.AllMustBeCorrect ?? false, Points = q.Points ?? 1, q.QuestionType, q.QuestionChoices }));


    var ColOfUaByQgroups =       from userAnswer in TestResult.UserAnswers
                      group userAnswer by userAnswer.QID into AnswersByQuestionCollection
                      select new { AnswersByQuestionCollection, QID =AnswersByQuestionCollection.First().QID };

    var ColOfUaAndQdataJoin = from UaByQgroup in ColOfUaByQgroups join  QData in ColOfQDataForQ
                        on UaByQgroup.QID equals QData.QID select new { Qdata = QData, UserAnswers = UaByQgroup.AnswersByQuestionCollection, SID = QData.SID, QID = QData.QID };

    var ColOfUaQdataJoinGroupedBySec = from UaQdJoin in ColOfUaAndQdataJoin group
                UaQdJoin by UaQdJoin.SID into UaQdJoinBySec
                select new { UaQdJoinBySec, SID = UaQdJoinBySec.First().SID};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've got enough RAM for the data, an approach which will be efficient computationally, and in terms of database round trips, would be to read a table or joined tables from the first database into a Dictionary object then reference this in your LINQ to the the second database, something like:

```
var questions = db1.Questions.ToDictionary(x => x.QID);
var result = db2.UserAnswers
    .Select(x => new { Question = questions[x.QID], Answer = x })
    .Select(x => new { x.Question.QID, x.Question.QuestionText, x.Answer.LineId }); //etc.
```